# RX and TX counts on various intermediate interfaces between two VMs

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ethernet, packet

I am trying to figure out how the network stats are being reported when I send packets from within a VM to another VM on a different host. My network environment looks like the image below:

[image: network setup]

Basically, I have a macvlan bridge on top of vlan interface. The vlan interface is on top of physical interface. The VM/container uses the macvtap interface to send/receive packets.

I was assuming that the readings would be same for all since the packet traverses through them, but I got mixed results where the RX stats of vlan interface were 0. TX stats were about the same, not exactly same as sum of TX of macvtap1 and macvtap2. It looks like "NIC Ring Buffer" might have something to do with this, but couldn't find a good explanation for that. Can anyone please help me with this.

Any answers on how it is supposed to count for packets sent/received.

Comment: paravirtualizing NICs might skew stats...

Comment: why do you need `macvtap`, why not SR-IOV direct